# Print Current Mercurial Revision Hash?

Tags: hash, mercurial, revision

Is there a better way extract the current revision hash in Mercurial than

`hg log -l1|grep changeset|cut -d: -f3`

?

Part of my webapp deployment script "tags" the uploaded app tarball with its unique revision hash.

Comment: Note that `hg log -l 1` gives you the most recent changeset, not necessarily the one you're currently updated to! The -f flag limits hg log output to ancestors of he current working directory, so `hg log -f -l1` is closer to what you want.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Try:

```
hg id -i
```

Example:

```
$ hg id -i
adc56745e928
```

Comment: In case people miss the solutions below if you want the full hash use: `hg --debug id -i` if you want template support use `hg parent --template '{node}'`  Do not use `hg log -l 1`, its the latest repository changeset, not the current working copy changeset.

Comment: Using --debug in scripts isn't recommended, that output is less carefully controlled w/r/t backward compatibility.  Use the template. If you want to do it w/ log then use `.` dot as the revision.

Comment: Thanks Ry4an I had not idea about "-r ." referencing the current working copy revision.  That seems like the better move then switching from "log" to "parent".

Comment: No prob.  `hg help revisions` and `hg help revsets` has some crazy powerful shortcuts like that.

Comment: But it is not the most specific answer to the question, because afaik `hg id -i` prints only the short (12 characters) form of the global hash id and since `hg identify` lacks `--template` afaics there is no way to extract just the revision and nothing else since the [man page says](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#identify) it prints a summary.

Answer (score 47):

```
hg --debug id -i
```

This will output the long hash, with a plus if there are uncommitted changes.

Comment: That seems to be the default in 3.1.2

Comment: Downvoting because of Ry4an's [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485651/print-current-mercurial-revision-hash#comment14377031_2485923).

Answer (score 24):

You can use --template with the parent command, I use this to get the long hash:

```
hg parent --template '{node}'
```

Comment: The hg man page says `hg parents` is [DEPRECATED](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#parents), although perhaps that might not have been the case when you wrote this answer. If there is an uncommitted merge, there are [two parent revisions](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/UnderstandingMercurial#line-157).

Comment: Can someone tell us why hg parents is deprecated and what should we use instead?

Answer (score 17):

Summarising the answers and their responses, it seems that this is
the best way to print the *unique* (not short form) identifier
of the *current* version:

```
hg log -l 1 --template '{node}\n' -r .
```

Comment: Note if there is an [uncommitted merge](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/UnderstandingMercurial#line-157), the `.` (dot) only displays the [first parent](https://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revisions) of two parents of the working group.

Answer (score 9):

```
hg log -l 1 --template '{node|short}\n'
```

See [the docs](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html), paragraphs "The basics of templating" and following.

Comment: I wanted almost this, but with the long hash. Aliasing `lid` to `log -l 1 --template '{node}\n'` achieved exactly this - print the full revision ID.

Comment: This prints the most recent pulled changeset. Our working directory could be updated to an older changeset. To print the changeset we are updated to, use "hg id". The only problem is, "hg id" does not support templates nor have an option to print long hash (unless someone knows how to do that).

Comment: As Eiver said this does not print the actually revision in your working copy only the latest one in your repository.  Because using this solution could introduce tracking errors I have down voted this solution.

Comment: Ditto Joe's downvoting.  Also @Eiver use `hg --debug id -i` as is said elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

The most specific non-DEPRECATED command which due to the presence of `--template` can print only revision information if that conciseness is required (as implied by the question):

`hg log -l 1 -b . -T '{rev}:{node|short}\n'`

Or for unique long form of hash:

`hg log -l 1 -r . -T '{node}\n'`

The `-b .` or `branch(.)` (dot for branch name) [means the current working directory branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957604/creating-a-mercurial-log-for-a-specific-branch#comment35144586_12957698) and `-r .` means the current working directory revision, which is [documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485651/print-current-mercurial-revision-hash#comment14410883_2485923) in `hg help revsets` and [`hg help revisions`](https://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revisions).

Note if there is an [uncommitted merge](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/UnderstandingMercurial#line-157), the `.` (dot) only displays the [first parent](https://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revisions) of two parents of the working group.

Answer (score 4):

In case TortoiseHg is used, right-click the revision row in the Workbench and select "Copy hash" (as per [documentation](http://tortoisehg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/workbench.html)).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, don't use `log -l`.

Use `hg log -r .` to get detailed information, as opposed to using `hg id` whose output is limited and it does not support templates. You could also create a little alias like `here = log -r .` and use `hg here`. If you only want the hash use `hg log -r . --template '{node}\n'`.