# What is the name for the commit/head that corresponds to the local checked-out state?

Tags: mercurial

There is a commit in my hg repository with hash 123abc. This is the last commit I made in the repo. When I run `hg diff --from 123abc`, I see no output. When I run `hg log --graph`, I see an `@` next to 123abc.

In Git this commit would be called "HEAD". I'm not sure what it's called in Mercurial. It is not the "tip", because I pulled other changes after the last time I committed (and `hg log -r tip` shows commit 456def).

What is this commit/head called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mercurial calls this the "parent" or the "parent revision of the working directory", and you can see it by running `hg parent`, `hg id`, or `hg summary`.

You can refer to it as `.` with the `hg log` command:

```
hg log -r .  # show the commit message for the parent
```

Answer (score 1):

If `123abc` has no children, then it is a "head".

> A head is a changeset with no child changesets. The tip is the most
> recently changed head. Other heads are recent pulls into a repository
> that have not yet been merged.

(https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Head)

---

Regardless whether the current working directory derives from a head or a non-head, I would refer to the commit that precedes it as the "working directory parent" changeset or commit. (That may just be the term my team uses - not sure it is "official".)

The parent may be visible in a GUI tool (like Tortoise) or you can get it using `hg parent`.

---

Based on the statements about `456def` I'm a little confused whether it has no children, or not? (Maybe update the question to clarify / add more detail)

Comment: But what is the name of the specific head that corresponds to the files I can see in my repository? It's not just any head, it's special. What is it called?

Comment: Are you asking, if and only if the working directory corresponds to a head, what is the special name for that head?  I don't think I've ever heard a special term for that, not that this proves there isn't one.

Comment: Regardless whether the current working directory derives from a head or a non-head, I would refer to the commit that precedes it as the "working directory parent" changeset or commit. That may just be the term my team uses.

Comment: I think "parent of the working directory" is what I want. You can get it by running "hg parent" (although that command says that it is deprecated). Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330631/how-can-i-find-my-working-revision-in-mercurial

Comment: I happen to use the Tortoise HG GUI which always makes the parent easily visible, but yes `hg parent` should be the same thing.