# Creating a mercurial log for a specific branch

Tags: command-line, mercurial

Is it possible to pull changes for just a single branch vs. the entire repository.  We have parallel development on different branches and do not want changes from another build in the log.

```
hg log -r %baseversion%:%releaseversion% --style changelog >> hglog.txt
```

I tried doing this this way but it pulled every change between the base tag and the release tag.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you're using proper hg branches, then you should be able to use the --only-branch option:

```
hg log --only-branch my_branch
```

That will show the changesets only for a given branch.

*Edit*: Looks like "--only-branch" is deprecated, but depending on the version of mercurial you use it will still be there. See https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/log . If your mercurial is too new, you may only have the "-b"/"--branch" option.

Answer (score 20):

Also, to show logs only for current branch, ou can use dot instead of current branch name `hg log --branch .`

Comment: Perfect, this is what I needed, I didn't want to always remember my current branch name, as it often changes in my current workflow.

Answer (score 8):

Follow-up @criswell

Funny, `hg help log` know nothing about "--only-branch" option, but note `-b|--branch BRANCHNAME`
Also, for worst cases, branch() function in revsets

Comment: Yeah `--branch my_branch_name` worked for what I needed it for.  I assumed it was a type-o  There is no only command in mercurial.